# Changing legend title in ggpattern R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, corpus, ggpattern

So I am trying to visualize my data in R using the ggpattern package. The problem is that I can't seem to edit the legend's title using the guides function. Before I go further into that, let me show the data

```js
     tag Center  n n_tag      persen
1  lisan     же 11  2142 0.005135387
2 medrus     же  6  2588 0.002318393
3 medsos     же 14  2778 0.005039597
4  puisi     же 15  2622 0.005720824
5  lisan     ну 39  2142 0.018207283
6  puisi     ну 13  2622 0.004958047
```

And this is the visualization, using the ggpattern package:
[image]

As you can see, the title for the legend is currently "Center". I want to change it into "Legenda".

So far, this is the code that I have tried of using, but to no avail:

```html
judul <- paste("Sebaran leksikon", kata_difilter, "\n", "dalam Korpus Nasional Rusia") 
subjudul <- paste("Jumlah token: ", ftj)
viz_akhir <- ggplot(df_viz, aes(tag, persen, fill=Center)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat="identity",
                   position=position_dodge(),
                   pattern_color = NA,
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_density = 0.25,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.010,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.70,
                   aes(pattern=Center)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) + #untuk b&w
  theme_light() +
  labs(title=judul, subtitle=subjudul) +
  xlab("Tag korpus") + ylab("Persentase dalam korpus") +
  guides(pattern=guides_legend(title="Legenda"))
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold", size=15),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=8))
print(viz_akhir)
```

This is the visualization of that code:
[image]

It instead make a new legend in place of changing the legend from the ggpattern visualization.

Anybody knows the solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both the `fill` and the `pattern` aesthetic mapped to the same variable, so you can combine the legends simply by giving these aesthetics the same names.

You didn't include `kata_difilter` or `ftj` in your question, so the plot is not fully reproducible, but I have recreated a modified version of `judul` and `subjudul` so the following code should work for you:

```r
ggplot(df_viz, aes(tag, persen, fill = Center)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity",
                   position = position_dodge(),
                   pattern_color = NA,
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_density = 0.25,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.010,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.70,
                   aes(pattern = Center)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = 0.9) + 
  theme_light() +
  labs(title = judul, 
       subtitle = subjudul,
       x = "Tag korpus", 
       y = "Persentase dalam korpus",
       pattern = "Legenda",
       fill = "Legenda") +
  theme(plot.title    = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 8))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the help :)) I am a beginner on R and apparently I have posted the wrong picture too haha, sorry for that!